# Using encrypted password in settings.xml for dockerfile-maven-plugin

Tags: maven-plugin

We are using dockerfile-maven-plugin from spotify. The plugin configuration is below and also settings.xml snippet follows. Noticed that if we try to use encrypted password with master password configured in the settings-security.xml, dockerfile-maven-plugin fails. Question is whether dockerfile-maven-plugin allows us to use encrypted password or not.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>push</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <repository>host:port/${project.artifactId}</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <buildArgs>
      <EAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.ear</EAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
    <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**settings-security.xml**

```
<settingsSecurity>
    <master>{Ve/ckepqKaIHGVED4WvoUn3htWLfPef158/35o9gdcM=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>host:port</id>
        <username>zenDocker</username>
        <password>{rdSNF21NPqMH70L7wKs1ZKg4nWF+8m+Hm3rFrpt/a+g=}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using this maven extension:

```
<extension>
  <groupId>com.github.shyiko.servers-maven-extension</groupId>
  <artifactId>servers-maven-extension</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</extension>
```

Reference I used: https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/password-encryption-in-the-liquibase-maven-plugin/

My config results the following:
**settings.xml**

```
<server>
        <id>hub.example.com</id>
        <username>myUsername</username>
        <password>{q6S7TmCyTP0H0q0IGOSsgnHSdbQlwXRcAF6h4Jvh/b0=}</password>
</server>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>com.github.shyiko.servers-maven-extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>servers-maven-extension</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>

<plugins>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${com.spotify.dockerfile-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <repository>hub.example.com/${project.artifactId}</repository>
        <useMavenSettingsForAuth>true</useMavenSettingsForAuth>
        <buildArgs>
            <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [README.md (v1.4.3)](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/blob/v1.4.3/README.md):

> Since version 1.4.3, using an encrypted password in the Maven settings file is supported. For more information about encrypting server passwords in `settings.xml`, [read the documentation here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Comment: You are right, when we started the version was 1.3.6 and looks like in latest version they have released a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem/question. Based on code at https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/com/spotify/plugin/dockerfile/MavenRegistryAuthSupplier.java#L50 and try-and-error exercises, password is expected to be in an open form

```
  return RegistryAuth.builder()
    .username(server.getUsername())
    .password(server.getPassword())
    .build();
```